# Scala code pattern for loading RDD or catching error and creating the RDD?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I would like to either load an RDD or, if that fails, create the RDD.  I thought this code below would work, but even though the sc.textFile() is inside the try block, it still fails.  What am I missing or how do I do this properly?  Thanks!

```
// look for my RDD, load or make it 
val rdddump = "hdfs://localhost/Users/data/hdfs/namenode/myRDD.txt"
val myRdd = try {
  sc.textFile(rdddump)
} catch {
  case _ : Throwable => {
    println("failed to load RDD from HDFS")
    val newRdd = [....code to make new RDD here...]
    newRdd.saveAsTextFile(rdddump)
    newRdd
  }
}

println(myRdd)
println("RDD count = " + myRdd.count)
```

and Error is thown as below

```
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://localhost/Users/data/hdfs/namenode/myRDD.txt
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:251)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:270)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:175)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:204)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:202)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:202)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MappedRDD.getPartitions(MappedRDD.scala:28)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:204)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:202)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:202)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1097)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:861)
...
```

Answer (score 4):

You're catching an exception in the wrong place, which your stack trace shows clearly. Calling `sc.textFile` does nothing except declare a relationship between some operation and an RDD. For example, nothing there triggers a computation that would cause it to check for the existence of the input.

Comment: yes, the exception happens as a result of the last line of code, when the myRdd relationship is executed to get the count.  I had expected the try/catch to still be effective.  Is there a way to force execution inside the try/catch or otherwise solve the problem?  thanks

Comment: You have to perform an operation -- like count. You can do so just to elicit the error. But then that wastes the effort. Instead try-catch around your 'real' call to count?